# How to display content of .txt file in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, file-io, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Like in topic. My question is - Is it possible and if yes, how to display content of .txt file in blazor app? I am using InputFile to load file from my computer. Below is my actual code which returns nothing.

```
<div class="col-4">
    <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChanged"></InputFile>
</div>

<p>
    @fileContent
</p>

@code{
    private string fileContent = "";

    private async void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.File;

        var buffer = new byte[file.Size];
        await file.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);

        fileContent = $"{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
@page "/"
<h3>ShowTextFile</h3>
<div class="col-4">
    <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChanged"></InputFile>
</div>

<pre>
    @fileContent
</pre>

@code{
    private string fileContent = "";

    private async Task OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.File;
        long maxsize = 512000;

        var buffer = new byte[file.Size];
        await file.OpenReadStream(maxsize).ReadAsync(buffer);
        fileContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working. I have one more question. OpenReadStream() is limited to files smaller than 500kb. How can i workaround this with larger files?

Comment: See the definition `public System.IO.Stream OpenReadStream (long maxAllowedSize = 512000, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)`.   See my revised answer

Comment: Thanks once again! You helped me a lot!